# Scroll Bars are not showing in mobile deivces until it's scrolled,

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

Here I have added a table with max height if it exceeds the height then custom scroller shows.The issues is it's not showing on mobile devices until its scrolled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP1nk.png)

```
.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend {
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--grey-dark);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px var(--grey-dark);
}

.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I want to keep them on mobile devices even it's not scrolled.

Comment: If you want persistent scrollbars use `overflow: scroll` for both horizontal and vertical, `overflow-x: scroll` for just horizontal, and `overflow-y: scroll` for just vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your`overflow-y: auto;` to `overflow-y: scroll;` in `.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend`. If the issue persists, comment out all your custom scrollbar styles below and then retry it.

Comment: This works for android. For IOS it's not working.For IOS it shows IOS default scroll bar if we scroll.

Comment: @dsands iOS removed the support of custom CSS for scrollbarsr since iOS 14. [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/lfi4ek/ios_14_safari_stopped_supporting_custom_css_for/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure yet, but can you try to change your `overflow-y: auto` into `overflow-y: scroll`?

```
.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend {
 max-height: 120px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 touch-action: pan-y;
 -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 8px;
}

.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-color: var(--grey-dark);
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px var(--grey-dark);
}

.scan-by-blocks .scan-by-block .legend::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This works for android. For IOS it's not working.For IOS it shows IOS default scroll bar if we scroll.

Comment: I'm not sure about its possibility of working on the iPhone.

Comment: I updated my post, can you try it?